# How to show custom error message on forced error inside a JsonResult

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a JsonResult where I do some validation and set the response status code to 400 and return a Json with a custom variable named errorMessage.

In the view I have the normal JQuery AJAX code, and in the error section I want to access to the value in the variable errorMessage.

How to declare the function() inside the error section in JQuery AJAX code.

```
// JsonResult action method
public JsonResult QuitarMiembro(string Id)
{
    if (Id == null)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(new { errorMessage = "Null Id" });
    }
}
```

```
//JQuery AJAX
function MyFun(Id) {
    console.log(Id);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("QuitarMiembro", "MiembrosJD")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { IdUsuario: Id },
        success: function (data) {
            fnMostrarMensajeExito(data.message);
            tablaMiembrosJD.ajax.reload();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data.errorMessage);
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: you have the error function, try consoling the data property, it should have the body of the request

Comment: execute `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` function when your code throw exception, but you are returning custom `json` object that can not get in error function. but you can handle exception by status like ` if (jqXHR.status == 404)`, `if (jqXHR.status == 500)` like this.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for error msg

```
function MyFun(Id) {
console.log(Id);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("QuitarMiembro", "MiembrosJD")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { IdUsuario: Id },
    success: function (data) {
        fnMostrarMensajeExito(data.message);
        tablaMiembrosJD.ajax.reload();
    },
   error: function (data) {
        alert("Error:" + data.errorMessage);`
    }
 });
```

}

Comment: That code is fine for the client side, however the alert says "Error: Undefined", but in the server side I have this line after setting the response.statuscode to bad request: return Json(new { errorMessage = "The Id is null" });